# Force MongoDb to use UUID instead of ObjectId

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to use pure json-data (without de-/serializing in the service) to store in MongoDB and read back and deliver pure json.
The only think I would need is, MongoDB should create "_id" as UUID instead of ObjectId.

If I have the following json:

```
[ { 'name': 'Data1' },
  { 'name': 'Data2' } ]
```

and insert this to MongoDB with the c# MongoDB.Driver 2.16.0 I get the following json back:

```
[{ "_id" : ObjectId("62b5765ab43274529aa913c1"), "name" : "Data1" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("62b5765ab43274529aa913c2"), "name" : "Data2" }]
```

where MongoDb is using the ObjectId type.
How do I force MongoDB to use UUID instead of ObjectId?

Here the code to insert the records:

```
var testColl = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test", new MongoCollectionSettings() { GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Unspecified });
var testJson = "[{'name':'Data1'},{'name':'Data2'}]";
testColl.InsertMany(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument[]>(testJson));
```

Comment: how do you insert these records?

Comment: it looks like there is no easy way to do it, the only way without implementing deep custom serialization is to manually add `_id` value to the inserted document

Comment: This is what I'm doing in another project.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine this simple workaround though:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("db");
        var testColl = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coll", new MongoCollectionSettings() { GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Unspecified});
        var testJson = "[{'name':'Data1'},{'name':'Data2'}]";

        var res = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument[]>(testJson);
        testColl.InsertMany(res.Select(d => new BsonDocumentWithId(d).ToBsonDocument()));
    }

    public class BsonDocumentWithId : IConvertibleToBsonDocument
    {
        public BsonDocumentWithId(BsonDocument doc) => Document = doc.DeepClone().AsBsonDocument;

        public BsonDocument Document { get; }

        public BsonDocument ToBsonDocument() => Document.Add("_id", new BsonBinaryData(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), BsonBinarySubType.UuidStandard));
    }
```

Comment: This is looking very promising. I'll try this on monday.